# how to use openquery in sql server if you have double quotes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a statement that uses double quotes like this:

```
select name as "My New Name" from my table
```

but would like to use something like this in openquery.  How do I do this?  I am  trying to use openquery but getting an error and I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.  Here is what I am trying to do. Please tell me if it is wrong.

```
select * from openquery(Test, 'SELECT Name as "New Name" from mytable ')
```

I am getting the following error

> The character string that starts with ' SELECT Name as "New Name.."

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008 and I don't have an issue with the double quotes.  One thing I do notice is that there's no database and schema for the table (at least in your code snippet).  That would be a problem.

Comment: Also, try changing the double quotes to square brackets - `[New Name]`

Comment: i think my issue is this error: the character string '' is too long. Maximum length is 8000 - Openquery.  do u know how to fix this?

Comment: Per MSDN, the max length of the query string is 8KB http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx

Comment: @moe no fix for that, it is a limitation of `OPENQUERY`. You can see that on this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx , under "Arguments"

Comment: @moe Please specify exactly what your problem is: you mentioned an error starting with "The character string..." but you didn't give the full error text and number. Then you said your error was a "maximum length 8000" error, but again without the full text. It's unclear exactly what your problem is. And you should also mention what your `Test` linked server is, in case it's not SQL Server.